# how to split a parent tag in xml twig?

Tags: perl

I am new to xml-twig, how can I split parent tag?

File:

```
<xml>
   <p class="indent">text text incluce <div>text</div> ateas</p>
   <p class="text">text text incluce <div>text</div> ateas</p>
</xml>
```

I need Output as:

```
<xml>
   <p class="indent">text text incluce</p>
   <div>text</div>
   <p class="indent">ateas</p>
   <p class="text">text text incluce</p>
    <div>text</div>
   <p class="text">ateas</p>
</xml>
```

How can I split tag?

```
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

open(my $output , '>', "split.xml") || die "can't open the Output $!\n";

my $xml_twig_content = XML::Twig->new(
        'p' => \&split, )

$xml_twig_content->parsefile("sample.xml");
$xml_twig_content->print($output);

sub split{
        my ($xml_twig_content, $p) = @_;

}
```

how can I split tag?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot depends on the nature of your complete XML data. If you expect nested `<p>` elements, for instance, then the solution is a lot more complex and the behaviour needs to be defined better.

However this program seems to do what you need, and works on your sample data. As in your own code, the `split` subroutine processes every `<p>` element that is encountered. An element is left untouched if all it contains is text, otherwise the children are detached and used to create a list of replacement nodes in array `@split`. The text nodes in this list are transformed by creating a clone of the parent `<p>` element and pasting the text as its contents. Once all text nodes have been modified, a call to `replace_with` substitutes the new list of elements for the original `<p>` element.

Note that the `print_to_file` method avoids the need to open the output file separately.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
  twig_handlers => { p => \&split },
);

$twig ->parsefile('sample.xml');
$twig->print_to_file('split.xml', pretty_print => 'indented');

sub split{
  my ($twig, $p) = @_;
  return if $p->contains_only_text;

  my @split = $p->cut_children;
  for my $child (grep $_->is_pcdata, @split) {
    my $text = $child;
    $child = $p->copy;
    $text->paste(last_child => $child);
  }

  $p->replace_with(@split);
}
```

**output**

```
<xml>
  <p class="indent">text text incluce </p>
  <div>text</div>
  <p class="indent"> ateas</p>
  <p class="text">text text incluce </p>
  <div>text</div>
  <p class="text"> ateas</p>
</xml>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are probably several ways how to do it. The following code uses `wrap_in`, which adds a new `<p>` around all the text nodes, and then `erase` to remove the original `<p>`. `atts` is used to copy the attributes of the original `<p>` to the new ones.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::Twig;

open(my $output , '>', "split.xml") || die "can't open the Output $!\n";

my $xml = XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { p => \&split_tag } );

$xml->parsefile("1.xml");
$xml->print($output);

sub split_tag {
    my ($twig, $p) = @_;
    $_->wrap_in('p', $p->atts) for $p->children('#TEXT');
    $p->erase;
}
```

BTW, please post a runnable code. Your sample code misses important parts (t.g. `twig_handlers` or a semicolon).

For your additional constraint, you can bend the script as follows:

```
sub split_tag {
    my ($twig, $p) = @_;
  CHILD:
    for my $ch ($p->children(sub {'div' ne shift->name})) {
        my $wrap = $ch->wrap_in('p', $p->atts);
        my $prev = $wrap->prev_sibling or next CHILD;
        $prev->merge($wrap) if 'p' eq $prev->name;
    }
    $p->erase;
}
```

Comment: nice, and without using XSH2! ;--)

Comment: @mirod: That was the question :-) The syntax is different, but the method would be the same.

Comment: K, it work well, But I need this also... <p>text <i>dsfakjl</i> <div>text</div> text <b>text</b> text</p> here, shouldn't assign para tag to div, but we need assign two para tag only. ex <p>...<i>..</i>..</p> <div>..</div> <p>... <b>...</b> ...</p>