# how can I split div tag only without any moveing?

Tags: perl

I am new XML-Twig... I want split para tag....

XML File:

```
<xml>
   <p class="indent">text <i>text<i> incluce <div>text</div> ateas</p>
   <p class="text">text text incluce <div>text</div> <b>ateas<b></p>
   <p class="text">text <p>text</p> incluce <div>text</div> ateas</p>
</xml>
```

Here I want split Para tags. How can I split and How can assign para tag without inline para tag and div tag...

I need output as:

```
<xml>
<p class="indent">text <i>text</i> incluce</p>
<div>text</div>
<p class="indent">ateas</p>
<p class="text">text text incluce</p>
<div>text</div>
<p class="text"><b>ateas</b></p>
<p class="text">text</p>
<p>text</p>
<p class="text">incluce</p>
<div>text</div>
<p class="text">ateas</p>
</xml>
```

How can I split this....

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Twig;
open(my $output , '>', "output.xml") || die "can't open the Output $!\n";
my $xml = XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { p => \&split_tag } );
$xml->parsefile("sample.xml");
$xml->print($output);
sub split_tag {
my ($twig, $p) = @_;
$_->wrap_in('p', $p->atts) for $p->children('#TEXT');
$p->erase;
}
```

But I can't get extract output.. How can I do this?

Comment: This is a dreadful question. All you have done is copied one of the solutions from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156289) and come straight back when you have found it doesn't do all that you need. I would expect you to have tried *something* to get it working for yourself - this isn't a site where you can get someone to do your work for you at no charge. Even the sample data you have posted isn't valid XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code seems to match your new requirements. If this doesn't work *please* try to fix it yourself before asking for more free code.

I have ignored the third line of your sample data as nested `<p>` elements are illegal in HTML.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
  twig_handlers => { p => \&split },
  pretty_print => 'indented',
);

$twig ->parsefile('sample.xml');
$twig->print_to_file('output.xml');

sub split{
  my ($twig, $p) = @_;
  return if $p->contains_only_text;

  my @children = $p->cut_children;
  my @newchildren;

  my $newpara = $p->copy;
  for my $child (@children) {
    if ($child->is_elt and $child->tag eq 'div') {
      push @newchildren, $newpara if $newpara->has_children;
      push @newchildren, $child;
      $newpara = $p->copy;
    }
    else {
      $child->paste(last_child => $newpara);
    }
  }

  push @newchildren, $newpara if $newpara->has_children;
  $p->replace_with(@newchildren);
}
```

**output**

```
<xml>
  <p class="indent">text <i>text</i> incluce </p>
  <div>text</div>
  <p class="indent"> ateas</p>
  <p class="text">text text incluce </p>
  <div>text</div>
  <p class="text"> <b>ateas</b></p>
  <p class="text">text <p>text</p> incluce </p>
  <div>text</div>
  <p class="text"> ateas</p>
</xml>
```